# How to modify and serve file content with User credential

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I want to modify the content of a file stored in the Google Cloud Storage bucket and serve it to the user. The delivery content will change based on the User profile.

By the following ways I am trying to achieve it.

1. User will request for a particular hash key, this key is mapped to a cloud storage url. The contents are read, modified and served to the User when the hash key is used in the url. Say `/serve/hash-key`.
2. User will not know the cloud storage url, nor will have a direct access to the content of the file.
3. Java servlet is mapped in the server-side to process the User request. To process all `/serve/*` queries.
4. User can do the request either through the current tab or through a new tab.

The problem what I am facing is when the request is processed in the Java Servlet, App Engine User details could not be fetched using `OAuthServiceFactory` class. `OAuthRequestException` is thrown when `getCurrentUser` Api is called.

Is there a possible way to achieve this or address the error?

Comment: if the user has no direct access, then basically you'll have to proxy the file for the user, which means you don't need the user's credentials to get at the file, you need your OWN credentials so your server can access gcs

Comment: @MarcB User credential is required for a different reason. The content serve will change based on the User data. This is must!